# Styling the "Share" action menu

Tags: android, styling, action-menu

I'm trying to add a "Share button" to my app, but I haven't found a way to manage the styling of the ActionMenu displayed to choose the app to share content to.

Currently it appears as in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

However, I'd like to change the background color and the text color to make them reflect the ones in the ActionBar: which are the style properties that handle these two colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest follow this tutorial and using the linked tool:

http://blog.stylingandroid.com/styling-the-actionbar-part-3/

[Jeff Gilfelt Android Action Bar Style Geberator tool](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100)

Quick mockup below, to prove it's very relevant and helpful in the direction of solving your question:

[image: quick mockup]

Comment: I see that it's inheriting styles from `@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow`, while I'm currently inheriting from `Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar` because I want to keep the compatibility to the lowest possible Android version. Is it going to work anyway?